# Tracking revisions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control

I'm looking to track some relatively basic revisions in a Rails instance built for project management. I've been surprised to find little on this topic, so I thought I'd post it here. Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place? I'll be clear near the top of this: I *don't* just want to use someone's gem (like Paper Trails), unless someone can tell me that's truly my only option. Consider this an exercise in theory more than an exercise in time best-spent for production.

My basic organization idea is this: one `Project` model with many `Revision` models, organized by `created_at`. The `Project` is basically just an ID, with most data housed in the `Revision`s. The first `Revision` contains all necessary data - which users are involved in the project, when it's due, etc. Then the easiest thing to do would be to duplicate that `Revision`, with changes, for each subsequent change. But that seems to be adding a lot of unnecessary data to the table every time, especially if only one of 12 fields is changed.

I'm pretty new with Rails, and so some of the MVC, more strongly object-oriented stuff is still kind of new to me. My idea would be to have the `Revision` only contain the `created_at`, the `User` who created it, and any of the fields that actually changed. But if that's the best strategy, how would I flatten this data in Rails? That is, if I had this table for `Revision`s:

```
Project_ID   | Title   | Description   | Due Date   | Created_at | Created_by
-------------|---------|---------------|------------|------------|-----------------
1            | Test    | Test project  | 9/28/2012  | 9/10/2012  | Ben
1            |         |               | 9/31/2012  | 9/13/2012  | Stuart
1            |         | Changed proj  |            | 9/13/2012  | Liz
```

And, in fact, this is the best way to do it, how would I flatten that to get `Test,Changed proj,9/31/2012` for `Project` with ID of 1? If this isn't the best way to go about it… what is?

The other thing to note, if it matters, is that some of these fields would connect to other Models through `has_many` and `has_many :through`. This, to me, ruled out the idea of having a `Revision` model with simply the name of the modified field, and the new content.

I'd like to do this without just using someone else's library. It feels like a relatively small problem that I just don't know how to start solving. But maybe I'm trying to open a much bigger can of worms than it feels like?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a fair amount on this topic. Here is a list of links that may help:

- [Railscasts episode on Paper Trail](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail)
- [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)
- [acts_as_revisable](https://github.com/fatjam/acts_as_revisable)

I would suggest you always check [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) for gems that you need and look at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) for tutorials.

Comment: OK, thanks, these are great gems as a resource, but assuming I didn't want to use those (as I indicated), assuming I'm trying to build this as a means of also learning, what's the _theory_ behind it? What about best practices? Short of reverse-engineering Paper Trail, what might I do to learn more about this stuff?

Comment: Go look at their source code basically. You're right in saying there isn't much out there that teaches this kind of thing, but as a learning exercise, I'd be going in and reverse engineering their code. Best practice though, don't reinvent the wheel. The whole ruby/rails community is actively developing thousands of gems to take care of so many problems, basically unless it's business logic or standard rails stuff, you can probably find a gem that will do it for you and you should be using it.

Comment: Alright, well … not helpful for my explained purposes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I can tell you with 100% certainty looking at the source code will be the best way to learn. :) For any production code though, you really should be using a proven solution.